# iPad position Fixed with textarea

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, css-position

I have a DIV placed in a fixed position at the bottom: 0. 
Inside there's HtML textarea. 
I wish that when I open iPad's keyboard remains at the bottom: 0, even when orientation changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the example below:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <center><textarea></textarea></center>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guinatal/3vCPu/